# I want to populate data in DataTable on button click, by default it should display no data available

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, datatable, datatables

**I am using NodeJs**

- I want to populate datatable on a button click.
- I am reading the data from a txt file.

> **home.ejs**

```
<button id="SearchButton" class="btn btn-info">Search</button>

<table class="table table-bordered" id="ctsdataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Check No.</th>
            <th>Tran Code</th>
            <th>ISN</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Check No.</th>
            <th>Tran Code</th>
            <th>ISN</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

> **home.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Table = $('#ctsdataTable').DataTable({
        "ajax": "js/data.txt",
        "columns": [{
                "data": "check_number"
            },
            {
                "data": "tran_code"
            },
            {
                "data": "isn"
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: doesn't matter if the table has no <tbody></tbody> tag ?

Comment: @simonecosci not required, that will be taken care by datatable itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way of doing this.

*While re-initializing the DataTable just put a property* **"destroy": true**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#ctsdataTable').DataTable({
    "columns": [
        {"data": "session_date"},
        {"data": "session_number"},
        {"data": "r_session_number"},
        {"data": "account"},
        {"data": "amount"},
        {"data": "check_number"},
        {"data": "tran_code"},
        {"data": "isn"}
    ]
});

$('#SearchButton').on('click', function () {
    $('#ctsdataTable').DataTable( {
        "destroy": true,
        "ajax": "js/data.txt",
        "columns": [
            {"data": "session_date"},
            {"data": "session_number"},
            {"data": "r_session_number"},
            {"data": "account"},
            {"data": "amount"},
            {"data": "check_number"},
            {"data": "tran_code"},
            {"data": "isn"}
        ]
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var yourTable = $('#ctsdataTable').DataTable({
    "columns": [
        {"data": "check_number"},
        {"data": "tran_code"},
        {"data": "isn"}
    ]
});

$('#SearchButton').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "js/data.txt",
        success: function (entries) {
            if (!entries)
                return;

                entries.forEach(function (entry) {
                yourTable.row.add(entry);
            });

            yourTable.draw();
        }
    });
});});
```

Comment: How I'll put data here in "entries" variable. That is a txt file

Comment: In this case we need to use FileReader to read txt file, but we can do it without that. And I am unable to do that.

Comment: @AdarshSingh I've updated my answer. Please, check it out.

Comment: When trying this code I am getting this error: 
`Uncaught TypeError: entries.forEach is not a function at Object.success (home.js:97)`

Comment: @AdarshSingh probably ajax response is an object and you should get entries from there and use forEach loop then.